# How do I properly print enumerator elements?

Tags: java, catalina

I am trying to understand java program written by someone else and I do not know java. I have written a short method fro dumping attributes of request object.

```
public void dumpRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {

    String[] attrNames = new String[100]; // hard coded
    int ani = 0;

    Enumeration rns = request.getAttributeNames();
    while (rns.hasMoreElements()) {
        out.println("attribute name: " + rns.nextElement());
        attrNames[ani] = rns.nextElement().toString();
        ani = ani + 1;
    }

    out.println("" + ani + " atributes");
    String cn;
    for (int n = 0; n < ani; n++) {
        cn = attrNames[n];
        out.println("** " + cn + " - " + request.getAttribute(cn));
    }
    out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++");

}
```

To my horror, I have realised that NetBeans variables tab shows twice more attributes on the request object compared to my code output.
The enumeration seems to be documented here:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/util/Enumerator.html

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you give an example output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call nextElement method **twice** in this block:

```
while (rns.hasMoreElements()) {
        out.println("attribute name: " + rns.nextElement());
        attrNames[ani] = rns.nextElement().toString();
        ani = ani + 1;
    }
```

you should call nextElement once. Put it in variable and then use that variable.

Comment: Completely read past that, nice spot :).  I guess he's just unlucky that its an even number of elements or else he'd get the NoSuchElementException.

Comment: @JohnHumphreys-w00te exactly! :-)